# How do I release or free /dev/ttyUSB0?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-2

I am trying to work with raw GPS data from a USB GPS receiver (Delorme LT-20) through `/dev/ttyUSB0/`.

My program had been working, but today I get this error:

> could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

The program is pretty simple:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: To rule out the obvious and assuming you made no other changes did you reboot.

Comment: What does `lsof` say?

Comment: [This](https://media.makeameme.org/created/Hello-IT-Have.jpg) never gets old.

Comment: Steve Robillard- No changes, reboot, power-down & restart, unplug & reinsert the USB device.  no change.  It had been working during my earlier experiments.

Comment: **Bex-** lsof output is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cqiw9s74n4ah832/lsof.txt?dl=0
I don't see tty or USB anywhere, but I did try gpsd a few days back- could there be a daemon running?  (If yes, how do I kill it?)

Comment: Yes, **Dmitry,** I see a lot of similar requests, but I'm sorry if I didn't use the exact search term to find the answer.  None of the two dozen or so solutions answered my specific question of how do I get my USB0 port back.

Comment: **Update**  Bex- 'sudo killall gpsd' _does_ allow me to open the ttyUSB0 port but when I reboot, the port is again busy.  I suspect that it's gpsd taking ownership of the port.  I don't plan to use gpsd, so is there a clean way to remove it or at least prevent it from running when it detects a GPS on the USB?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a rather old question, but since I had the same problem I wanted to share my solution (apart from turning it off and on again, which also helped): list the processes which are using the resource and `kill` them.

Two options are available for this:

```
$ fuser /dev/ttyUSB0
```

If that returns nothing, try

```
$ sudo lsof /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Then issue a `kill` using the `PID` contained in the return-value of the above listed commands.